# Python (3) flask to rebuild tables fails (usually) using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a few tables I wish to truncate and then repopulate (legacy and not how I'd do it but company won't pay to fix process) Code is logging the state but when it gets to truncate a table it is just hanging.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    print(str(datetime.utcnow()), 'Running Database Sync...')
    cur = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
    logging.info(cnx.is_connected())
    try:
        # Clear the database ready to re-import
        logging.info("Clear Tables")
        # Clear lookup tables first
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE member_additional_skills;")
        logging.info("Reset member_additional_skills")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        # cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_additional_skills AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
        # logging.debug("Reset inc member_additional_skills")
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE member_employment_status;")
        logging.info("Reset member_employment_skills")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        # cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_employment_status AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
        # logging.debug("Reset inc member_employment_status")
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE member_work_domain;")
        logging.info("Reset member_work_domain")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        # cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_work_domain AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
        # logging.debug("Reset inc  member_work_domain")

        cnx.commit()

        logging.info("Delete Members")
        # Clear members table
        sql = "DELETE FROM members;"
        cur.execute(sql)
        cnx.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)
```

So sometimes this is working but mostly it is failing on the first truncate call. The server isn't running out of memory and its cpu and load are reasonable. The first table (member_additional_skills) has 850 rows in it so should be a simple task right? I do not get any errors and the app hangs indefinitely after logging `Clear Tables`

I usually end up manually running this a few times and a few server reboots and it will either work or will continue to fail. The flask schedule call is on a cron job. Usually whatever i do fails and then suddenly it has worked (although this is not the case now for over a week).

*** EDIT This is the full function for completeness, the issue is however only happening at the point outlined above (after Clear Tables) ***

```
@app.cli.command()
def scheduled():
    """Run scheduled job."""
    logging.info("Start Scheduled Sync")

    # Compile regex for phone number validation
    phone_num_check = re.compile(r"^[0-9 ]+$")

    # Load the entire _member directory into a dict
    with open(config["Path"]["root"] + "opt/find-interpreter-db-populate/members.json", "r") as fp:
        members = json.load(fp)

    logging.info("Fixing Members")
    # Loop through each _member and fix the data
    for member_id in members:
        # Check if _member wants profile shown
        if 'show_profile' in members[member_id]:
            if members[member_id]['show_profile'].lower() == "yes":
                members[member_id]['show_profile'] = 1
            else:
                members[member_id]['show_profile'] = 0
        else:
            members[member_id]['show_profile'] = 0

        # Check that _member has a billing postcode
        if 'billing_postcode' in members[member_id]:
            if len(members[member_id]['billing_postcode']) > 2 and ' ' in members[member_id]['billing_postcode']:
                members[member_id]['postcode_area'] = members[member_id]['billing_postcode'].split(' ')[0].upper()

        # If we weren't able to get a postcode area then don't store this user
        if 'postcode_area' not in members[member_id]:
            continue

        # If the user is missing their first name or last name then don't use
        if 'first_name' not in members[member_id] or 'last_name' not in members[member_id]:
            continue

        if 'contact_tel' not in members[member_id]:
            members[member_id]['contact_tel'] = None
        else:
            members[member_id]['contact_tel'] = members[member_id]['contact_tel'].replace('+44', '0')
            members[member_id]['contact_tel'] = members[member_id]['contact_tel'].replace(' ', '')
            # If phone number not valid then don't store it
            if not phone_num_check.match(members[member_id]['contact_tel']):
                members[member_id]['contact_tel'] = None

        # If the user doesn't have a description then set it to None
        if 'description' not in members[member_id]:
            members[member_id]['description'] = None

        # If the user has work domains set then split them
        if 'work_domains' in members[member_id]:
            members[member_id]['work_domains'] = members[member_id]['work_domains'].split(', ')
        else:
            members[member_id]['work_domains'] = []

        # If the user has additional skills then split them
        if 'additional_skills' in members[member_id]:
            members[member_id]['additional_skills'] = members[member_id]['additional_skills'].split(', ')
        else:
            members[member_id]['additional_skills'] = []

        # Changed DIN Member from Yes/No to 1/0
        if 'din_member' in members[member_id]:
            if members[member_id]['din_member'] == "Yes":
                members[member_id]['din_member'] = 1
            else:
                members[member_id]['din_member'] = 0
        else:
            members[member_id]['din_member'] = 0

        # Change NRCPD from Yes/No to 1/0
        if 'nrcpd_registered' in members[member_id]:
            if members[member_id]['nrcpd_registered'] == "Yes":
                members[member_id]['nrcpd_registered'] = 1
            else:
                members[member_id]['nrcpd_registered'] = 0
        else:
            members[member_id]['nrcpd_registered'] = 0

        # Change full/associate/student _member types to FULL/ASSO/STUD for DB
        if 'full' in members[member_id]['membership_plan'].lower():
            members[member_id]['membership_plan'] = 'FULL'
        elif 'assoc' in members[member_id]['membership_plan'].lower():
            members[member_id]['membership_plan'] = 'ASSO'
        elif 'stud' in members[member_id]['membership_plan'].lower():
            members[member_id]['membership_plan'] = 'STUD'
        else:
            continue

        # Convert and split employment statuses (if set)
        if 'employment_status' in members[member_id]:
            emp_types = []
            if 'free' in members[member_id]['employment_status'].lower():
                emp_types.append('FREE')
            if 'empl' in members[member_id]['employment_status'].lower():
                emp_types.append('EMPL')
            members[member_id]['employment_status'] = emp_types
        else:
            members[member_id]['employment_status'] = []

        # If we have an avatar attachment ID, get the URL"
        if "wp_user_avatar" in members[member_id]:
            attachment_urls = get_attachment_url(members[member_id]["wp_user_avatar"])

            if attachment_urls:
                thumbnail_attachment_url = attachment_urls["thumbnail"]
                full_attachment_url = attachment_urls["full"]
                members[member_id]["avatar_thumbnail_url"] = thumbnail_attachment_url
                members[member_id]["avatar_full_url"] = full_attachment_url
            else:
                members[member_id]["avatar_thumbnail_url"] = None
                members[member_id]["avatar_full_url"] = None
        else:
            members[member_id]["avatar_thumbnail_url"] = None
            members[member_id]["avatar_full_url"] = None

        # Generate the _member key
        members[member_id]['member_key'] = (str(member_id) + "|" + app.config['SECRET_KEY']).encode("utf-8")
        members[member_id]['member_key'] = hashlib.sha256(members[member_id]['member_key']).hexdigest()[-10:].upper()

        # All data valid - we'll want to add it to the DB so set the add field
        members[member_id]['add'] = True

    print(str(datetime.utcnow()), 'Running Database Sync...')
    cur = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
    logging.info(cnx.is_connected())
    try:
        # Clear the database ready to re-import
        logging.info("Clear Tables")
        # Clear lookup tables first
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE member_additional_skills;")
        logging.info("Reset member_additional_skills")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        # cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_additional_skills AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
        # logging.debug("Reset inc member_additional_skills")
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE member_employment_status;")
        logging.info("Reset member_employment_skills")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        # cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_employment_status AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
        # logging.debug("Reset inc member_employment_status")
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE member_work_domain;")
        logging.info("Reset member_work_domain")
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        # cur.execute("ALTER TABLE member_work_domain AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;")
        # logging.debug("Reset inc  member_work_domain")

        cnx.commit()

        logging.info("Delete Members")
        # Clear members table
        sql = "DELETE FROM members;"
        cur.execute(sql)
        cnx.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed truncating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    try:
        logging.info("Rebuilding Members")
        # Loop through each _member. If add is set, add to the database
        for _member in members:
            this_member = members[_member]
            if 'add' in this_member:
                sql = """INSERT INTO members (id, member_key, first_name, last_name,website_url, email, 
                                contact_tel,postcode, postcode_area, description, membership_type_id, 
                                nrcpd_registered,din_member, show_profile,avatar_thumbnail_url, avatar_large_url, rnd) 
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

                member_data = (_member, this_member['member_key'], this_member['first_name'], this_member['last_name'],
                               this_member['website_url'], this_member['email'], this_member['contact_tel'],
                               this_member['billing_postcode'], this_member['postcode_area'],
                               this_member['description'],
                               this_member['membership_plan'], this_member['nrcpd_registered'],
                               this_member['din_member'],
                               this_member['show_profile'], this_member["avatar_thumbnail_url"],
                               this_member["avatar_full_url"], random.randint(0, 50000)
                               )

                cur.execute(sql, member_data)
                cnx.commit()

        logging.info("Lookup Data")
        # Do lookup data
        for _member in members:
            this_member = members[_member]
            if 'add' in this_member:

                # Additional skills first
                for additional_skill in this_member['additional_skills']:
                    # Check if additional skill already exists
                    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM additional_skills WHERE name = %s", (additional_skill,))
                    result = cur.fetchall()

                    # If the additional skill doesn't already exist, create it
                    if cur.rowcount == 0:
                        cur.execute("INSERT INTO additional_skills (name) VALUES (%s)", (additional_skill,))
                        add_skill_id = cur.lastrowid
                    else:
                        add_skill_id = result[0]['id']

                    cur.execute(
                        "INSERT INTO member_additional_skills (member_id, additional_skills_id) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                        (_member, add_skill_id))

                # Do work domains
                for work_domain in this_member['work_domains']:
                    # Check if work domain already exists
                    cur.execute("SELECT id FROM work_domains WHERE name = %s", (work_domain,))
                    result = cur.fetchall()

                    # If the work domain doesn't already exist, create it
                    if cur.rowcount == 0:
                        cur.execute("INSERT INTO work_domains (name) VALUES (%s)", (work_domain,))
                        work_dom_id = cur.lastrowid
                    else:
                        work_dom_id = result[0]['id']

                    cur.execute("INSERT INTO member_work_domain (member_id, work_domain_id) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                                (_member, work_dom_id))

                # Do employment status
                if 'employment_status' in this_member:
                    for employment_status in this_member['employment_status']:
                        sql = """INSERT INTO member_employment_status (members_id, employment_statuses_id) 
                                    VALUES (%s, %s)"""
                        cur.execute(sql, (_member, employment_status))

            cnx.commit()

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(str(datetime.utcnow()), error)
        print(str(datetime.utcnow()), "MySql Error Code: ", error.errno)
        print(str(datetime.utcnow()), "MySql SQLSTATE: ", error.sqlstate)
        print(str(datetime.utcnow()), "MySql Error Message: ", error.msg)
        logging.debug("Start Scheduled Sync")

    logging.info("Finished!")
    print(str(datetime.utcnow()), 'Sync finished.')
```

I am considering removing the truncate sections and updating existing data if it exists or adding entry if it doesn't exist but my python/mysql isn't too strong

Comment: "when it gets to truncate a table it is just hanging" - sounds like a lock.

Comment: And how do i check for that or handle it correctly?

Comment: So I did some googling on locks and worked out a solution using a truncate function but this took the app down. It then built correctly using my original code :-s